# posting form to php page causes .php file download

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, post, redirect

**C# Code**

```
Response.Clear();

string postbackUrl = "https://payeer.com/ajax/api/api.php";
string account = "620913";
string orderid = "77777";
string amount = Convert.ToDecimal(IncreaseUSDtxb.Text).ToString("N2");
string units = "USD";
string key = "test1";

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("<html>");
sb.AppendFormat(@"<body onload='document.forms[""form""].submit()'>");
sb.AppendFormat("<form name='form' action='{0}' method='post'>", postbackUrl);
sb.AppendFormat("<input type='hidden' name='m_shop' value='{0}'>", account);
sb.AppendFormat("<input type='hidden' name='m_orderid' value='{0}'>", orderid);
sb.AppendFormat("<input type='hidden' name='m_amount' value='{0}'>", amount);
sb.AppendFormat("<input type='hidden' name='m_curr' value='{0}'>", units);
sb.AppendFormat("<input type='hidden' name='m_key' value='{0}'>", key);
sb.Append("</form>");
sb.Append("</body>");
sb.Append("</html>");

Response.Write(sb.ToString());

Response.End();
```

Usually this code allows me to post data to third party websites, redirect user to them and to retrieve answer using the following:

```
System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection ReadForm = Request.Form;
yourvariable == ReadForm["requestedcolumn"]
```

This happens without errors when I use ".asp" page in my postbackUrl as url to post to. 
However, in this case the abovementioned code causes api.php to be downloaded, though I can open https://payeer.com/ajax/api/api.php in my browser giving a blank page of course with no problem.

How to overcome the issue of this code downloading .php page instead of redirecting to it?

Update: Solved. Apparently, for some reason, if you specify a link in otherwise correct format in PostBackUrl or Form Action without "www" it downloads in this case specifically ".php" resource instead of redirecting to it which it does with "www" included.

I am yet unsure if the post action works correctly in my code on which I will update, though it should as it works correctly in cases of non-php third party resources.

Comment: I was notified by Stack Exchange inbox at the top left corner there is a comment to this current post which starts with "What happens if you put a php file in your web root and navigate to it? Something trivial li..." How do I view it, please?

Comment: I can't seem to find the solution anywhere. a href='' and Response.Redirect works fine, BUT PostBackUrl='' and Form Action='' cause every php file to be downloaded which may be cosidered a separate issue I am unable to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

Well to ilustrate how I do data POST to websites, user login is saved between request and request2:

```
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.website.net/login.php");
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        byte[] query = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("uid=login&pwd=password");
        request.ContentLength = query.Length;
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(query,0, query.Length);
        }
        var response = request.GetResponse();
        var str = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

        HttpWebRequest request2 = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.website.net/index.php");
        request2.Method = "GET";
        request2.CookieContainer = request.CookieContainer;//<-pass cookies
        var response2 = request2.GetResponse();
        var str2 = new StreamReader(response2.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: Thank you Full_Int. My code works fine as well. Now I am certain it has something to do with my Visual Studio WebSite Project. If I set html link "<a href=" inside my .aspx file asp:Lable control's Text property to point to php page, it works fine. If I set asp:LinkButton's PostBackUrl Property to point to php page it downloads the file instead of redirecting. If I set form's action property - it downloads the file instead of redirecting.

Comment: By the way, others may argue if CookieContainer is safe, has sufficient integrity or should be used to store anything at all, but your code does HttpWebRequest only, it does not actually redirect user to the page in question. It sends data and requests it.